# return to zero after reach max value and add the remaining value javascript

Tags: javascript, html

sorry i am newbie here

i need some help,

this case like notice a time.

when real time passes input value, then span with id alertLabel will change.

the problem is, if input value plus with input with id Duration will exceed real minutes or hours.

this is my code example.

javascript.js

```js
var alertLabel = document.getElementById("alertLabel");
var less = document.getElementById("lessThan").value.replace(":", "");
var late = document.getElementById("timeIn").value.replace(":", "");
var duration = parseInt(document.getElementById("Duration").value);
var outs = document.getElementById("timesOut").value.replace(":", "");

var lessInt = parseInt(less);
var lateInt = parseInt(late);
var outsInt = parseInt(outs);
var durationOut = outsInt + duration; // this will be exceed
var durationIn = lateInt + duration; // this will be exceed

function getAlert() {

  let times = new Date();
  let sh = times.getHours() + "";
  let sm = times.getMinutes() + "";
  let ss = times.getSeconds() + "";
  let shLong = sh.length == 1 ? "0" + sh : sh;
  let smLong = sm.length == 1 ? "0" + sm : sm;
  let ssLong = ss.length == 1 ? "0" + ss : ss;
  let shSm = shLong + smLong;
  document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = shLong + ":" + smLong + ":" + ssLong;

  if (shSm >= outsInt && shSm < durationOut) {
    alertLabel.innerHTML = "OUT!!";
  } else if (shSm >= lessInt && shSm < lateInt) {
    alertLabel.innerHTML = "hurry up, don't be late!!";
  } else if (shSm >= lateInt && shSm < durationIn) {
    alertLabel.innerHTML = "LATE!!";
  } else {
    if (shLong >= 21 || shLong <= 4) {
      alertLabel.innerHTML = "good dream tonight !!";
    } else if (shLong >= 5 && shLong <= 11) {
      alertLabel.innerHTML = "spirit Morning !!";
    } else if (shLong >= 12 && shLong <= 17) {
      alertLabel.innerHTML = "happy Noon !!";
    } else if (shLong >= 18 && shLong <= 20) {
      alertLabel.innerHTML = "nice evening !!";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body onload="getAlert();setInterval('getAlert()',1000)">

    <span id="clock"></span>
    <span id="alertLabel"></span>
    <div></div>
    <input class="" type="text" id="lessThan" value="13:45" name="lessThan"> <!-- when time to in is near -->
    <input class="" type="text" id="timeIn" value="13:48" name="timeIn"> <!-- time in and get alert Late -->
    <input type="text" id="timesOut" value="13:55" name="timesOut"> <!-- value time to out and get alert Out -->
    <input type="text" name="Duration" id="Duration" value="5"> <!-- duration alert for id timeIn and timesOut if more than 100 is the problem, this input as minute -->


</body>
</html>
```

this is my last try, example in input id timeIn

```
var a = document.getElementById("timeIn").value.split(":");
for (var i = 0; i < duration; i++){
var b = parseInt(a[0]); // this for hours
var c = parseInt(a[1]); // this for minutes
var x = c + i;
    if (x >= 60){
        var n = b + 1;
        x = x-60;
    }
        console.log(x);
}
```

in my last try, in log var x return to zero just once

and the question is, if input value with id duration more than 100, how looping, if each var x reach value (60) his return to zero and var c plus 1 each var x reach 60.
maybe anyone have an easier one to solve this case.
sorry if the explanation is unclear.